# How can I get a hint of a particular value from a type any?

Tags: typescript

I have a value that I hope can be of any type, but it has a special meaning for a particular value, such as the following code:

```js
type TT = any | {cancel?: boolean}

const a: TT = ...
```

I want the editor to tell me when I type 'a.' that there might be a cancel attribute under A. How can I do that?

P.S. The scenario I have is that I have a value that is returned through the network interface, so it is any, but I know that it can make an error, and when it does, the value will be assigned as the error object, so I have this requirement.I hope that when I do something with this value, the editor will tell me that it might have an error object, and then let me see some properties underneath the error object.

Answer (score 0):

One way which I think this maybe to add an `interface` that extends `TT` and includes the `cancel` property. Something like:

```js
interface CancelableTT extends TT {
  cancel?: boolean;
}

const a: CancelableTT = ...;

if (a.cancel) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Comment: As you answered, if I inherit any type, I can indeed meet the requirements of the question, but this does not seem to be written succinctly enough, I wrote an example：[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiKBeKBDBBuAUASzsCAJwDNUBjaAFUqggA8C4ATAZ1gSgG8speoz0FADYB+AFxQARgHtpQiOiwBfLFiYQyQ1IWhlpcFsDQTqGIA)

Comment: @Autumn Sorry I didn't understand. Based on your question I tired answering. Can you please explain your requirement in the comment once?

Comment: Your answer solves this problem, but I don't know how to disaggregate a utility type so that this type logic can be reused, for example: `type TT = AnyWith<{cancel? : boolean}> `It would be very convenient if it could be used in this way

Comment: ok as I could surmise you're expecting this? `type AnyWith<T> = any | T & {cancel?: boolean};`

Comment: Check out the links below, where I've made the problem more specific：[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiA6gS2ACwDwBUB8UC8UAhglAPRlQCSAtmADYQ0RzBTrIDO7A9j-QCghQilAC0EyVIlQAEhABO0IkvZpowCJzYBjIpy0CAJhB30V0RmyIAuWAhToMAbz1wdEegH47AIz6MJAC+OADcQkQAdG4e9ARQAIwATADMoeSUWGhcUJxoPACu9EZQSmA8CtZwUIoKFRHxySkZUFlEbHmFxVC+0ArIAOZowA2EwAoF0KJtHflFJb2lg8OjUABEOptrLTO5c92L-UMjQA)

Answer (score 0):

You may write you type like

```
type TT = { cancel?: never } | { cancel: boolean }


let a: TT = {} as any

let b = a.cancel
// let b: boolean | undefined
```

This will work for numbers/strings, but won't work for a=null (which is a runtime error)